# Crop the object area in an mage

Tags: image-processing

[image]How to crop the object in the image by black pixel or white pixel area. I want the idea or any code for this. Bounding box is in Matlab. But here we are not have the bounding box options.

[image: Find the object scerew]

```
x = Import["/home/karthi/Desktop/Length/5.jpg"];
adj = Sharpen[x];
MorphologicalBinarize[x1];
```

I only tried this. Just I need to detect the black pixel area as bounding box

Comment: Please describe your problem in more detail,  at the moment it is quite unclear what exactly you want to do. Optimally including code to show what you tried already.

Comment: Err ... you have _several_ black areas there. Or perhaps you posted the image **after** the `MorphologicalBinarize[ ]`?

Comment: yes,But any way, I want the object area in the image

Comment: This is my image @belisarius has settled

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: K. Once more thank u too. I have more doubts here. I will ask later, when I try @belisarius-has-settled

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
i = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsutA.jpg"];
tvf = TotalVariationFilter[i, Method -> "Laplacian"];
ImagePad[i, -BorderDimensions[
         Dilation[DeleteSmallComponents[EdgeDetect[tvf, .9]], 5]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This crop image is not exactly comes, In top screw head is cut out in small length

Comment: @MuthuKumar Add a safety padding as you see fit. Don't expect "please solve my problem completely" kind of answers in this site!

Comment: Its OK. Am not say You are wrong. Just intimate to you. And try to know what is that error. Thats only @belisarius-has-settled

Comment: @MuthuKumar There is no "error", but just a boundary adjustment (very usual when  using image processing methods).  That said, there you have it.

Comment: Ya ok. If you are ok. Please accept my invite in @belisarius-has-settled